# Would privatizing Social Security "solve" Occupy Wall Street?

Tags: united-states, taxes, social-security, privatization

The Democrats [oppose privatizing Social Security](http://www.ontheissues.org/celeb/Democratic_Party_Social_Security.htm) because it wouldn't be fair to those who have already given money into the system.

The Occupy Wall Street movement was founded on the rich having a disproportionate ownership of the economy. Privatizing Social Security would give every worker ownership of the economy and thereby decrease the portion owned by the rich.

Right now there is over $1 trillion sitting in Social Security as US treasuries. What would be the economic consequences if that money would go back to those who paid into it as privatized savings accounts? People are currently "saving for retirement" as well as paying into social security. They would no-longer have to pay for retirement twice.

A reasonable way to calculate who would get how much of the current surplus of Social Security would be to take everyone alive as of today and add up all the money they have paid into social security. Then divide the current surplus by that number to determine what fraction of the money paid in an individual will receive back in their individual retirement account.

Would privatizing Social Security address the demands of Occupy Wall Street?

Comment: There's some confusing of concepts here. "Privatizing social security" isn't necessarily just "giving the money back". Most proposals would have the money put into private investment. Also, there's some bad math...people aren't "saving twice" for retirement. They're "saving for retirement because Social Security won't be enough to get by on alone". Finally, since Occupy was primary focused on income inequality, suggesting that retirement funds be funneled into investment banking is pretty much what they were against.

Comment: It's actually more like [2.610 trillion](http://www.ssa.gov/oact/trsum/).

Comment: @DA. The concepts are not confusing: The words following "give the money back" read "to those who paid into it as privatized savings," which is what you proceeded to describe as a widely proposed idea. The math isn't bad: people are saving for their parents in SS as well as for themselves. Your statement about income equality being the focus of Occupy Wallstreet has little to do with privatization: Investment banking is optional. They can buy and sell on e-trade if they want. I would be fine if they wanted to buy gold and bury it somewhere in the Ozark Mountains.

Comment: You're correct, you did state "privatized savings" though that's not exactly what the proposals state. The proposals typically suggest that private investment firms would handle the investing. All that aside, it really has nothing to do with the Occupy movement--which is about income inequality, of which privatizing Social Security has little bearing on.

Comment: Let's assume the Occupy Wallstreet movement was founded on the rich having a disproportionate ownership of the economy. The question is: Would privatizing Social Security make the economy ownership *proportionate*?

Comment: @Trylks, No. I don't think anyone would consider 6% of the national GDP a very large proportion of the economy. (Especially if you divide it up among the 99%)

Comment: @user1873 then most of the problem would remain "unsolved"...

Comment: @Trylks Is the glass 6% full or 94% empty?

Comment: @Peir both, and mostly empty.

Comment: @Trylks without 6%, it is completely empty.

Comment: This question originally read like it wanted to advertise a political idea. We generally try to phrase questions in a neutral tone which doesn't try to influence the reader. I edited the question accordingly.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> Would privatizing Social Security address the demands of Occupy Wall-street...?

It would not meet the demands of Occupy Wall Street (OWS).

The demands of OWS revolve around [income disparity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Occupy_Wall_Street#Overview).  Their [stated goals](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Occupy_Wall_Street#Goals) (such as reducing the influence of corporations on politics and a more balanced distribution of income) would not be resolved by privatizing social security and, arguably, oppose said goals. One such argument would be pointing out that Wall Street is the home of the very private investment investment firms that would benefit from privatizing Social Security (which are the same firms that OWS is protesting).

Answer (score 2):

**No, Occupy Wall Streets was concerned with income disparity. Privatizing the SS Trust fund would have a tiny effect on income**

[Occupy Wall Street](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Occupy_Wall_Street#Overview) main concern was income inequality.

> The Occupy protesters' slogan "We are the 99%" refers to the protester's perceptions of, and attitudes regarding, income disparity in the US and economic inequality in general, which have been main issues for OWS.

Even if you divided out the [$2.610 trillion](http://www.ssa.gov/oact/trsum/) among the bottom 20% ([about 63 million people](http://www.census.gov/popclock/)), and allowed them to collect dividends off their portion at a modest 8% return, it would only amount to a paltry source of income.

> (2,610,000/62.78)*0.08 = $3,325 per person/year.

Comment: 8% is *modest*?  I sure would like to know where you're investing...

Comment: @BenCollins, yes [8% is modest](http://financeandinvestments.blogspot.com/2012/06/historical-annual-returns-for-s-500.html). 8% is on the low end of Stock investments. If you compare averages over long periods of time, "the standard returns for the stock market historically are closer to 10%" [Managed Funds vs Index](http://www.fool.com/School/MutualFunds/Performance/Record.htm).

Comment: @user1873 - we are in the **"new normal"**. You won't see 8% again in sustained way.

Answer (score 1):

In general, the proposals to privatize Social Security did not involve the money already paid into it.  Instead, privatization would have reduced the money going into the Social Security trust fund and, for those who chose to do it, have reduced the money that would later come out for those same people.  Since the Social Security trust fund receives a higher interest rate than other debt, this would have reduced the long term spending without reducing spending for anyone who did not choose to participate.

This made sense in 2005, when proposals were being floated.  But it wouldn't really work now, when there is no significant surplus being deposited into the Social Security trust fund.  The idea had been that some people would already be retiring with lower Social Security because they had chosen to participate.  That reduction in expenditures would have allowed for other people to bypass Social Security now.  But since that didn't happen, there is no significant Social Security surplus.  In fact, a few years back, Social Security paid out more than it received.  In a few years, we can expect that to be the new normal.

The claim that privatization was going to take money away from current retirees was a scare tactic.  It never represented the reality of any proposal under serious discussion.

> This move would stimulate the economy since many people are currently "saving for retirement" as well as paying into social security. They would no-longer have to pay for retirement twice.

But when you "stimulate" an economy that is not in recession by cutting savings in favor of consumption, it causes inflation.  The Federal Reserve would then cut the money supply (which causes interest rates to rise to meet a higher target).  The economy would shrink or at least grow more slowly.

What you really want to do is to *increase* savings.  Higher savings leads to more investment, which leads to productivity increases, which increases production, causing inflation to drop.  Then the Fed expands the money supply and the economy grows at a faster rate.

The notion that consumption "stimulates" economic growth is one of the most pernicious of the neo-Keynesian falsehoods.  If they actually read John Maynard Keynes work, they would know that it is *investment* that stimulates economic growth.  That's why Keynes advocated things like building roads and bridges during a recession.  Because there was an investment shortage which he wanted the government to fill counter-cyclically.  Then, when the recession would be over, Keynes wanted the government to run a surplus.  But no one ever finds that part of his advice convenient.

> take everyone alive as of today and add up all the money they have paid into Social Security

Again, that's not how they suggested it would work.

The idea was that an individual would choose to take part of that individual's contributions to Social Security for the current year and put that money in an investment account (e.g. an Individual Retirement Account).  In return, that person would accept a lower return from Social Security based on the contribution reduction.  The idea being that the Net Present Value of the reduction in payments would outweigh the value of the foregone contribution.  So the Social Security system would have been made stronger by each person who chose to do this.  Because its obligations would have dropped more than its revenues.

The Soviet Union tried something like what you suggest.  They gave citizens stock in the previously government owned companies.  Most of the citizens then turned around and sold the stock immediately to finance consumption.  Who bought?  Well, now we call those people Russian oligarchs.  Rather than empowering citizens, it lead to an overwhelming concentration of assets.

That's pretty much the reverse of what the Occupy Wall Street people wanted.

Answer (score -4):

I think privatizing social security would help the poor people in this country become very wealthy indeed. Lets look at how it works. Its commonly stated on the Dave Ramsey program that people should save 15% for their retirement. The amount of money saved pretax for social security is about 15%. If you put in a modest 500 dollars a month for 40 years you would have about 1.7 million dollars saved for retirement assuming an 8% return. This money could be saved for your heirs as well since social security balances and earning go away once you and your spouse die. Maybe a transfer tax could be included to help people less fortunate and for expenses. But if you compare that to maybe 1500 dollars to 2000 a month from social security when your 67 the 1.7 million dollars is much better. This would help families get out of poverty. The same goes for a federal or state pension once you die generally the spouse gets a portion but after that its wiped out and nobody gets it. If it was privatized the money would be generational and people could dig their selves out of poverty. Think of all the jobs that and wealth that would be created thru privatizing these things. A disability insurance plan could be taken out to take care of things like on the job injury and other maladies which keep people from working. It could also include longevity insurance at 60 which would ensure that a nursing home would not suck all the money that you saved for away. The government should put money into the program at birth maybe a 5000 investment which would turn into over 1 million when the baby turned 67. The person could pay two and a half time the money back when he or she starts working and that could in turn give another 2 babies a head start. With the remaining amount going to expenses.

Comment: I don't think you understand how little money "poor people" or "familes in poverty" actually have. Many, many people simply can't afford to invest $500 a month. I'm pretty sure my parents certainly wouldn't, and my family are hardly impoverished. Also, an 8% return on *anything* seems really generous, where are you getting that figure from?

Comment: At full time minimum wage, social security withholding (employer+employee) amounts to about $180, so even removing SS but mandating that the same withholding be applied to a 401(k) type private plan is a long way from "a modest 500 dollars a month".

Comment: A second too late to edit previous comment: should read $150 per month, not $180.